If multiple people are managers of multiple laboratories, are they "Laboratory Managers" or "Laboratories Managers"?
I'm not sure what plurality to use in these different cases.

Person who manages one lab = Laboratory Manager.
Person who manages many labs = Laboratory Manager / Laboratories Manager?
Many people who manage one lab = Laboratory Managers
Many people who manage many labs = Laboratory Managers / Laboratories Managers?


Whatever their responsibilities, and however many labs they manage, they are laboratory managers.

Here "laboratory" is an attributive noun. Have a look at these questions.

One person, one truck, one person, ten trucks, ten people, one truck, ten people, ten trucks, they are all truck drivers, and each is a truck driver.

But as always there are exceptions.  For example, we often say Facilities Manager in AmE. A person responsibile for a clinical trial involving multiple labs might be called a Laboratories Coordinator.

So the answer can depend on the actual context.

I add to what @Michael Harvey said. Attributive nouns are more commonly singular.  This applies to this post, as shown in the
Ngram.
The answers to the OP's four examples are hence laboratory manager for (1) and (2), and laboratory managers for (3) and (4).
The plural form of this attributive noun laboratories
may have its usage, but it is much less common than the singular one; it is not even captured in Ngram.

I'll add: Sometimes we see phrases that sound weird, in which the plural form of a two-word noun phrase makes the first word plural (surgeons general, accounts payable), but this is because we don't have an attributive noun here, we have a noun followed by an adjective, which is an unusual order.

Thanks, @Andy Bonner.  Yes, general and payable here are postpositive adjectives.
